# Extract all entries from a pandas df where the values are the same across all years

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this (with many more other countries, this is a sample):

```
df_dict = {'country': ['Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan', 'Greece','Greece','Greece','Greece','Greece','Greece','Greece'],
           'year': [2016, 2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2016, 2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022],
           'value': [320, 416, 172, 652, 390, 570, 803, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,100]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

I want to extract all the entries where the `value` is the same across all years. Sometimes it could be `100`, sometimes it could be another value, but the example here is with `100`.

I'm not really sure how to go about this

The output should look like this.

```
df_dict2 = {'country': ['Greece','Greece','Greece','Greece','Greece','Greece','Greece'],
           'year': [2016, 2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022],
           'value': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,100]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df_dict2)
```

Comment: Do you need the value or just the country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the countries that have the same value across all years use [`groupby.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
s = df.groupby('country')['value'].nunique()

out = list(s[s.eq(1)].index)
```

Output: `['Greece']`

If you also want the value, go for a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) through [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
(df.groupby('country')['value'].agg(['nunique', 'first'])
   .loc[lambda d: d.pop('nunique').eq(1), 'first']
)
```

Output:

```
country
Greece    100
Name: first, dtype: int64
```

##### edit: filtering the original DataFrame:

```
s = df.groupby('country')['value'].nunique()
df[df['country'].isin(s[s.eq(1)].index)]
```

Or directly:

```
df[df.groupby('country')['value'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
   country  year  value
7   Greece  2016    100
8   Greece  2017    100
9   Greece  2018    100
10  Greece  2019    100
11  Greece  2020    100
12  Greece  2021    100
13  Greece  2022    100
```

Comment: `df[df.groupby('country')['value'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]` - is the most pretty among all others

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest but slower than the `isin` approach (`transform` is expensive) ;)

Comment: and what's the fastest from all you posted? Assuming that the first 2 are only filters to obtain the expected df slice

Comment: @Roman actually after some tests this is pretty similar. I guess it depends on the exact data (size, number of groups) and the pandas version…

Comment: on the current input sample `transform` approach runs about 2 times faster that `isin + agg + pop`

Comment: @Roman Comparing the last 2 approaches (in the *edit*) it's within 10% of each other for me (pandas 1.5.2).

Comment: Actually, even `df.groupby('country').filter(lambda x: x['value'].unique().size == 1)` gives about the same timing. Too small data input to play with.